# pointer to const member function typedef

Tags: c++, function, pointers, member, function-qualifier

I know it's possible to separate to create a pointer to member function like this

```
struct K { void func() {} };
typedef void FuncType();
typedef FuncType K::* MemFuncType;
MemFuncType pF = &K::func;
```

Is there similar way to construct a pointer to a const function?  I've tried adding const in various places with no success.  I've played around with gcc some and if you do template deduction on something like

```
template <typename Sig, typename Klass>
void deduce(Sig Klass::*);
```

It will show Sig with as a function signature with const just tacked on the end.  If to do this in code it will complain that you can't have qualifiers on a function type.  Seems like it should be possible somehow because the deduction works.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You want this:

```
typedef void (K::*MemFuncType)() const;
```

If you want to still base `MemFuncType` on `FuncType`, you need to change `FuncType`:

```
typedef void FuncType() const;
typedef FuncType K::* MemFuncType;
```

Comment: Yes you are right it works!  I thought I tried this second one, but guess not, that was another machine though maybe old compiler.  Will have to check again tomorrow.

Answer (score 11):

A slight refinement showing how to do it without a typedef.
In a deduced context like the following, you can't use a typedef.

```
template <typename Class, typename Field>
Field extract_field(const Class& obj, Field (Class::*getter)() const)
{
   return (obj.*getter)();
}
```

applied to some class with a const getter:

```
class Foo {
 public:
  int get_int() const;
};

Foo obj;
int sz = extract_field(obj, &Foo::get_int);
```

Answer (score 3):

Another more direct way to do it (avoiding `using` and `typedef`s) is this:

```
#include <iostream>

class Object
{
    int i_;
public:
    int j_;
    Object()
        : Object(0,0)
    {}
    Object(int i, int j)
        : i_(i),
        j_(j)
    {}

    void printIplusJplusArgConst(int arg) const
    {
        std::cout << i_ + j_ + arg << '\n';
    }
};

int main(void)
{
    void (Object::*mpc)(int) const = &Object::printIplusJplusArgConst;

    Object o{1,2};
    (o.*mpc)(3);    // prints 6

    return 0;
}
```

`mpc` is a const method pointer to `Object`.