# const function pointers

Tags: c++, function, pointers, function-qualifier

I'm have some difficulties with function pointers. I have an base class which defines a function pointer that via **typedef double (*function)(double *x) const;**

- A quick side question: why does the above typedef not compile?

  Gives the following error: **error: ‘const’ and ‘volatile’ function
  specifiers on ‘function’ invalid in type declaration**

For the part below I use **typedef double (*function)(double *x)**.
Now each daughter class can implement multiple and different versions of functions of this type. Via an enum I select the function of my choice, which sets my non-member function pointer (defined in the base class) to be initialized by one of these member-function pointers of the daughter class. Here's a code snippet:

The source file of the daughter class:

```c
PndLmdROOTDataModel1D::PndLmdROOTDataModel1D(interpolation_type intpol_type) {
  if(intpol_type == CONSTANT) {
    setModelFunction(&PndLmdROOTDataModel1D::evaluateConstant); 
  }
  else if (intpol_type == SPLINE) {
    setModelFunction(&PndLmdROOTDataModel1D::evaluateSpline);
  }
  else {
    setModelFunction(&PndLmdROOTDataModel1D::evaluateLinear);
  }
}
```

And the base Class (header file):

```c
class MultiModel1D: public Model1D {
protected:
  function model_func;

public:
  MultiModel1D();
  virtual ~MultiModel1D();

  void setModelFunction(function f);
}
```

When compiling I get the following error:

> note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘double
>   (PndLmdROOTDataModel1D::*)(double*)’ to ‘function {aka double
>   (*)(double*)}’

I'm using the function pointer, because of speed issues (at least I think this should be faster than constantly running through some switch case). What am I doing wrong? Maybe there is also some design pattern that will serve as a better alternative... Thanks in advance!

Steve

Comment: possible duplicate of [pointer to const member function typedef](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3050805/pointer-to-const-member-function-typedef)

Comment: The bottom error says it all. Function pointers are not the same as member function pointers. http://liveworkspace.org/code/1iUxos%242

Comment: ordinary function cannot be const??

Comment: I'm confused. Which bit is your question? You appear to have several.

Comment: Just like member functions aren't the same as functions (remember, member functions have a "hidden" `this` argument), member function pointers aren't the same as function pointers. You are trying to stuff member function pointers into function pointers.

Comment: The const part is understood, thx! But why can't I cast a member function pointer to a non-member function pointer. Why does the compiler care about that? I can see that he says its not the same.. So does that mean the thing I want to do, is just not possible or is there a solution. Making the function pointer a member function pointer in the typedef doesn't help I think, because I have several daughter classes. Hence one member function pointer would be initialized by another type.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

That is because there is a fundamental difference between a (free-)function pointer and a member function pointer. You "side question" already contains the hint to the problem. To explain, you can do either this:

```
typedef double (SomeClass::*function)(double *x) const;
```

or

```
typedef double (*function)(double *x);
```

but a non-member function can never be declared `const` on the function level. Those types can not be converted to each other and this is the problem in your code that the compiler is pointing out.

If they *could* be converted, you would end up with a problem: The member function pointer tells the compiler that it needs an object to be called with, which will be put into `this` when the member function is called. If the pointer could be casted to a normal function pointer, this object would be missing and probably all parameters would be messed up as a consequence. So, no, you really can't just cast them. The reality is even more complicated (multiple/virtual inheritance), but you get the picture...

Comment: thx for the insanely fast answsers! I got the const part for non-member functions making no sense. But for the second error I took out all of the const. Basically my question would be why can't the compiler cast a member function pointer to a non-member function pointer.

Comment: @steve: I added an explanation.

Answer (score 8):

For the same reason that we shall not write:

```
void foo() const
{
   // ...
}
```

outside of a class declaration. Non-member functions cannot be `const`.

Your function pointer is a normal function pointer, not a pointer-to-member-function and, as such, `const` has no meaning there.