# How to declare a member function const pointer while point to const address

Tags: c++, constants, pointer-to-member

What I mean is something like `const char* const p;` or `char const * const p;`. The `p` here stand for a pointer points to a const char while the pointer itself is also const.
So `*p = 'a';` or `char c = 'c'; p = &c;` won't be complied.

Please someone tell me how to declare a pointer points to a member function, both what it points to and itself is const, with and without `typedef`.

Not use in practice just curious about.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3050805/pointer-to-const-member-function-typedef) is not what I'm asking about.

Comment: What's the problem with the question you linked?

Comment: @Jeffrey- That question is about pointing to a member function that's const. I think this question is about making a const pointer to a member function.

Answer (score 4):

Member function pointers can't be dereferenced to modify the pointee, so only one const is needed:

```
RetType (Class::* const ptr)(Arg1Type, ..., ArgNType) = ...;
```

With typedefs:

```
typedef RetType (Class::* PtrTypedefName)(Arg1Type, ..., ArgNType);
const PtrTypedefName ptr = ...;
```

Hope this helps!