# How do I Declare a Method Pointer That's Constant

Tags: c++, constants, function-pointers, c++03, pointer-to-member

1<sup>st</sup> off this isn't a question about how to point to a constant method. I want to know how to make my method pointer constant.

Given:

```
struct foo {
    void func1();
    void func2();
};
```

I can construct a method pointer with `void (foo::*bar)() = &foo::func1` *but* I can later do `bar = &foo.func2` and I want to prevent that.

I can easily do this with `const auto bar = &foo::func1`, but I'm not sure how to do this pre [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11).

Comment: Is a `typedef` considered cheating?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to declare a member function const pointer while point to const address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20699916/how-to-declare-a-member-function-const-pointer-while-point-to-const-address)

Comment: @MSalters I mean a `typedef` is probably what I'd do... but I did really want to see the signature in all of it's glory.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All you have to do is to add the `const` keyword after the `*`, like this:

```
void(foo::*const _pointer)() = &foo::func1;
```