# What does A::* mean where A is a class type

Tags: c++, boost

I've read the implementation of boost::is_class.It's obviously using SFINAE. 
And I've coded another`is_class` by myself.
I noticed that there's a `void(A::*)(void)` in boost's source code.
What does that mean exactly.

Here is my code:

```
#include<iostream>

template<typename T>
struct is_class
{
    typedef const char yes_type[1];
    typedef const char no_type[2];

    template<typename A>
    static yes_type& test(void(A::*)(void));
//What's A::*
    template<typename A>
    static no_type& test(...);

    const static bool value = sizeof(test<T>(0)) == sizeof(yes_type);
};

struct A{};
int main()
{
    std::cout<<is_class<A>::value<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: or maybe this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3050805/pointer-to-const-member-function-typedef

Comment: or any of these: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/member-function-pointers?sort=votes